# Why couldn't Andrei sleep?

Tags: character, europa-report

In *Europa Report*, why was Andrei sleep-deprived? Was it because he had failed to save James during the EVA accident?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Andrei is having sleep issues because of the incident with James. When Andrei regains consciousness he howls in despair because he realized what happened. It was his fault. This occurred at 6mo into the mission.

At 8mo into the mission Daniel is taking Andrei's blood pressure and asking if he is sleeping well. His response is no.

The whole team is still distraught a year later as we see in a scene at 19mo with Rosa trimming Katya’s hair and Katya saying,

> it’s been over a year since we lost him.

Sources:

- [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2051879/synopsis)
- [The Movie Spoiler](http://www.themoviespoiler.com/Spoilers/europareport.html)
- Memory

Comment: Any comment as to why the down-vote was necessary?

Comment: I too wonder why, your answer was the one I came in to propose.